# Windows 7 doesn't dim the screen as far as Windows 10

Tags: windows, brightness

I want to start out by saying I'd rather avoid third party programs like Dimmer, PangoBright, etc if possible. I don't think I need them, since I know my hardware is capable of what I want.

I have a tri-boot of Windows 10, Windows 7 and Ubuntu. In both Windows 10 and Ubuntu, I can get the screen very dim, so in a dark room I can barely see the keyboard. However, in Windows 7, the screen doesn't go nearly as dim; it's maybe 25% brighter at its minimum compared to the other OSes.

I know my screen can go dimmer than Windows 7 allows it, because it works on other OSes. It almost looks like Windows 7 has some arbitrary limit set somewhere that doesn't actually reflect my hardware's capabilities.

Is there some way I can adjust this lower limit in Windows, without using a screen overlay to "darken" the screen?

This is a laptop:

- MSI GP60 2QF
- NVIDIA 950m/Intel 4600

It did come with Windows 8.1, but the support page provides drivers for Windows 7 (which I have installed).

(Since MSI's website is weird: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GP60-2QF-Leopard-Pro.html)

Comment: And how exactly do you actuall _dim_ your screen, please?

Comment: @ClassStacker I'm not sure I understand, but I use the Fn-key combo: down and up arrow keys.